# Flex email validator - £ symbol allowed in domain name

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, validation, flex3

I have a bug to fix in work where the UK Pound symbol, £, is allowed in the domain name.

I checked the EmailValidator source and can see that it is not a disallowed symbol, whereas things like the dollar sign are:

```
public class EmailValidator extends Validator
{
    include "../core/Version.as";

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Class constants
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    private static const DISALLOWED_LOCALNAME_CHARS:String =
                                "()<>,;:\\\"[] `~!#$%^&*={}|/?'";
    /**
     *  @private
     */                         
    private static const DISALLOWED_DOMAIN_CHARS:String =
                                "()<>,;:\\\"[] `~!#$%^&*+={}|/?'";
```

As you can see DISALLOWED_DOMAIN_CHARS string does not include the £ sign. Was thinking of monkey patching (basically copying the entire class, editing it, and adding it to my src - for those not in the know), but we use RSL's, so that would be problematic.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You should override the method **doValidation** of Class **mx.validators.EmailValidator** like this rather than clone a Class

```
override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array
        {
            var results:Array =  super.doValidation(value);

            var emailStr:String = String(value);
            var poundPos:int = emailStr.indexOf("£");
            if (poundPos != -1)
            {
                results.push(new ValidationResult(
                    true, null, "invalidChar",
                    this.invalidCharError));

            }

            return results;                      
        }
```

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Why do you *need* to disallow it?

<sub>This rhetorical question brought to you by the number 42 and the letters S and O.</sub>

---

There are *so many other* symbols that you're not asking about specifically banning. I'd suggest deciding to blacklist "only a few" like you are now, or else completely rethink your validation process to a whitelist format.

Comment: @Tomalak - Although, there is'nt too many other symbols on a standard UK/US keyboard that are missing: £€¬ are the only ones I can think of

Comment: @Brian: Input can be performed in other ways than pressing a single key on a keyboard. Think about charmap, programmatic approaches or even Alt-codes! I can write Alt+0215 on my keyboard and produce `×`. Is that a valid character for your algorithms?

Comment: @Brian: If you're validating input you ought to validate input properly, IMO. Validating only trivial cases seems rather pointless. But each to their own.

Comment: Completely agree.  I'd just ignore it and have the server side validate it as well.